# javascript ile link çektirme

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

After entering the link in the input type, when we press the button, I want to have the picture link taken to the profile picture.

How can I prevent this or when I press the new button again, how can I delete the previous picture and put the new picture in its place?

I am new to jquery and javascript, I would be glad if you could help me.

```js
function protocolCheck(link) {
  var proto = ['http:', 'https:'];

  for (var i = 0, len = proto.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (link.indexOf(proto[i]) === 0) {
      return link;
    }
  }

  return document.location.protocol + '//' + link;
}

function createImage(e, src) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var parent = this.parentNode;
  src = protocolCheck(document.getElementById('resim-linki').value);

  var img = document.createElement('img'),
    a = document.createElement('a');
  img.src = src;

  a.appendChild(img);
  parent.parentNode.insertBefore(a, parent.nextSibling);
  img.style.width = "100px";
  img.style.height = "100px";
  img.style.borderRadius = "50%";

}

var addButton = document.getElementById('btn');
addButton.onclick = createImage;
```

```css
.Phone {
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
  height: 580px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(24, 89, 173);
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 95px;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: #f0efef;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px rgb(172, 172, 172, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 320px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="Phone">
  <div class="profile"> </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control text-muted" id="resim-linki" style=" position: absolute; top: 250px; width: 220px; left: 40px; border-radius: 50px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The `createImage` function expects 2 arguments. The `event` is passed by default when you call `addButton.onclick = createImage;` but the second argument `src` will be missing

Comment: It looks like `src` isn't needed as a parameter since it is calculated within that function.

Comment: @James indeed that appears to be the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the `a` elements you create are added at the root level, and not within a container, you could apply a class to identify them. Then when the button is next clicked you can select all the `a` elements with that class and `remove()` them from the DOM. Something like this:

```js
function protocolCheck(link) {
  var proto = ['http:', 'https:'];
  for (var i = 0, len = proto.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (link.indexOf(proto[i]) === 0) {
      return link;
    }
  }

  return document.location.protocol + '//' + link;
}

function createImage(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  removeExisting();

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = protocolCheck(document.getElementById('resim-linki').value);
  img.style.width = "150px";
  img.style.height = "50px";
  img.style.borderRadius = "50%";
  img.title = new Date().getTime(); // just to show the image is being updated 

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.classList.add('foo');
  a.appendChild(img);

  var parent = this.parentNode;
  parent.parentNode.insertBefore(a, parent.nextSibling);
}

function removeExisting() {
  document.querySelectorAll('a.foo').forEach(el => el.remove());
}

var addButton = document.getElementById('btn');
addButton.addEventListener('click', createImage);
```

```css
.Phone {
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
  height: 580px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(24, 89, 173);
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 95px;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: #f0efef;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px rgb(172, 172, 172, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 320px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="Phone">
  <div class="profile"> </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control text-muted" id="resim-linki" style=" position: absolute; top: 250px; width: 220px; left: 40px; border-radius: 50px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

An alternative method would be to place the new `a` elements within a container, such as a `div`, and then simply wipe the `innerHTML` of that container when you want to create a new child instance .